# How to execute the query only when mainframe is up?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which has to be executed only when the mainframe is up. Mainframe is down during these hours
tuesday to saturday - 1am to 6am,
sunday - 1am - 12pm.

I am trying to declare a variable which gets the current date and time and then trying to write a logic in the if statement to satisfy the above condition.

```
if @new_que_stat_cd = 'U'
BEGIN

--declare @recv_time datetime  = getdate()
--if  CASE WHEN datepart(dw,@recv_time) in ('SUNDAY') AND 
--,'TUESDAY','WEDNESDAY','
--declare @ident int =  IDENT_CURRENT( 'SADEV.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl' )
UPDATE NEW SET [ETQueueCtrlStatusCd] = 'U'
       from sadev.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl NEW
       where new.[ETQueueCtrlStatusCd] = 'S'  
       AND new.ErrorFl = 'N'
       and new.VendorTransactionID is not null
       and new.VendorTransactionIDRcvdDate is not null
       and new.ETQueueCtrlID = @queuectrl_id

select new.VendorTransactionIDRcvdDate
from sadev.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl NEW
where new.[ETQueueCtrlStatusCd] = @new_que_stat_cd 
       AND new.ErrorFl = 'N'
       and new.VendorTransactionID is not null

       and new.ETQueueCtrlID = @queuectrl_id
END
```

WILL THIS LOGIC WORK FOR THE ABOVE CONDITION

```
 declare @recv_time datetime  = getdate()
if   (convert(varchar,(datepart(DAY,@recv_time))) in ('SUNDAY') 
                    AND convert(varchar, @recv_time, 114) between convert(datetime,'01:00') and convert(datetime,'12:00')) 
                    or
     convert(varchar,(datepart(DAY,@recv_time))) in ('Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday') 
     AND convert(varchar, @recv_time, 114) between convert(datetime,'01:00') and convert(datetime,'06:00')
```

Comment: will this work for the above query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on: [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Try this:

```
IF @new_que_stat_cd = 'U'
BEGIN
DECLARE @currDate DATETIME=GETDATE();
DECLARE @runProcess BIT=0;
SELECT @runProcess=CASE
                       WHEN DATEPART(dw, @currDate) IN
                                                       (3, 4, 5, 6, 7
                                                       )
                       THEN CASE
                                WHEN DATEPART(hh, @currDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
                       WHEN DATEPART(dw, @currDate) IN
                                                       (1
                                                       )
                       THEN CASE
                                WHEN DATEPART(hh, @currDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 12
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
                       ELSE 0
                   END;
IF @runProcess = 1
BEGIN
UPDATE NEW
       SET ETQueueCtrlStatusCd='U'
FROM sadev.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl NEW
WHERE new.ETQueueCtrlStatusCd = 'S'
      AND new.ErrorFl = 'N'
      AND new.VendorTransactionID IS NOT NULL
      AND new.VendorTransactionIDRcvdDate IS NOT NULL
      AND new.ETQueueCtrlID = @queuectrl_id;
SELECT new.VendorTransactionIDRcvdDate
FROM sadev.RO_Transcript.ETQueueCtrl NEW
WHERE new.ETQueueCtrlStatusCd = @new_que_stat_cd
      AND new.ErrorFl = 'N'
      AND new.VendorTransactionID IS NOT NULL
      AND new.ETQueueCtrlID = @queuectrl_id;
END;
END;
```

Where 3,4,5,6,7 are Tuesday to Saturday respectively and 1 is Sunday.

Comment: Hi The above query not giving any error, but data is not updated in the table.

Comment: do you know if the conditions are being met and the IF @runProcess = 1 clause executes?